# In-App to unlock other In-Apps with hosted content (iOS)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I'm working on an app where there are many in-apps with apple hosted content.
I want to have an "Unlock All" in-app that will allow user to get other existing & future in-apps for free.

How would I set this up?

I can only think one idea: When user purchased that "Unlock All" in-app, it will make all the other in-apps for free, so when user clicks the other in-apps to get the content, they would get the hosted content for free.

So, I need to create 2 in-app IDs for each in-app. And upload 2 hosted contents for each in-app.
First one is for the paid one. This will be available for users that haven't purchased the "Unlock All" in-app.
And the second one is for the free one, that will be displayed only when user has purchased the "Unlock All".

I'm not sure if this workaround will be allowed by Apple and I can't put my contents on my server for some reasons.

So, does anyone know if this workaround will be allowed by Apple, or if there's a better idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps for this:

1. Add two non consumable products in your iTunesConnect account for your application. (Your first product type could be changed but second one (purchase all) should be Non-consumable).
2. Now talking about all purchase, when user have purchased this product, you can save the payment recipt generated by apple to your server or can save a boolean value in local database of your application.
3. Now when user taps on first product button, you can check for the recipt and perform desired actions.